# how pass list to datatable net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am building an api that receives json text string which uses the post method to save the information in the database, I use a stored procedure to carry out this process, I am using a list that is what brings me the json information, but I need to pass the information to a datatable so that it can be uploaded as a parameter to the stored procedure, but I can't make the conversion and I can't traverse the list with a foreach because it tells me it's not an uncountable element.
The structure of the json file is as follows:

```
{

    "varios":[{
    "name":"David",
    "cant":"291123",
     "number":"205893",
        },
        {
    "name":"pedro",
    "cant":"295523",
     "number":"206693",
        },
            {
    "name":"maria",
    "cant":"295523",
     "number":"206693",
        }
    ],

}
```

I built the list according to the json arguments like this

```
public class cadena
    {
        public List<lista> vari { get; set; }


    }

    public class lista
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int cant { get; set; }
        public int number { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I built my controller in the following way where format is my previously formatted list

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] cadena formato)
        {
             await _repository.Insert(formato);
            return Ok();


        }
```

And now I bring the list information to another method where I should execute the stored procedure, where it suggests I should pass my list to datatable

```
public async Task Insert(cadena formatos)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                                          //
                             DataTable dt = new DataTable();


                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_pruebatype", sql))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tipo", dt));
                    await sql.OpenAsync();
                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

I built my datatable but I don't know how to pass the list to my datatable and then send it as parameter to my stored procedure
I appreciate your help

Comment: I think where you're using IEmunerable should pass value by foreach method.And you should also show what stored procedure you wrote. I guess it's  better to simply pass value by three paramaters.

Comment: If you are using microsoft sql server, and you want to pass in a `DataTable` object, then you will need to create a `User-Defined Table Type` that matches the structure of the `DataTable` you wish to pass in. there is a lot of other stuff you have to do also. Have you defined the `User-Defined Table Type` for your `DataTable`?

Answer (score 0):

First we need to flatten the json and make it each line list use selectmany

```
var result = cadena.SelectMany(x=>x.vari.select(v=> new {v.name,v.cant,v.number})).ToList();

//pass that query and to make datatable

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
// add  column with respective names
dt.Columns.Add("col_name", typeof(String))
dt.Columns.Add("col_cant", typeof(String))
dt.Columns.Add("col_number", typeof(int))

// pass the data into respective column and add to the datatable
foreach (var item in result)
{
  DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
  dr["col_name"] = item.name;
  dr["col_cant"] = item.cant;
  dr["col_number"] = item.number;
  dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

By doing this your data table is ready

Let me know if any issues facing while doing this